# Magento Cache filling up forver

Tags: magento-1.9, block-cache

We have a magento 1.9 store, and there is a constant problem with the **cache** follder growing, over 50gb in 2 weeks.

The mage--9 folder seems to hold most of that, and there are few milions file with namkes and content like this:

`mage---internal-metadatas---590_FFFFD3ECB5F39120351F01E2611DD7B3`

```
a:4:{
s:4:"hash";
i:159752789;s:5:"mtime";
i:1450156222;s:6:"expire";
i:1450159822;s:4:"tags";
a:11:{
    i:0;s:14:"590_BLOCK_HTML";
    i:1;s:27:"590_CACHE_BLOCKHTML_OBJECTS";
    i:2;s:35:"590_MAGE_CATALOG_BLOCK_PRODUCT_LIST";
    i:3;s:22:"590_CATALOG_CATEGORY_3";
    i:4;s:26:"590_CATALOG_PRODUCT_105545";
    i:5;s:22:"590_CATALOG_CATEGORY_3";
    i:6;s:22:"590_CATALOG_CATEGORY_4";
    i:7;s:22:"590_CATALOG_PRODUCT_73";
    i:8;s:22:"590_CATALOG_CATEGORY_2";
    i:9;s:22:"590_CATALOG_CATEGORY_3";
    i:10;s:8:"590_MAGE";
    }
}
```

We are using NytroGento cache,
And admin Cache refresh is not responding ..
And our Products have a crazy structure with lots of option.

Any pointers on what the problem may be ?

Comment: According to the documents make sure your cron is working:  `Clean old cache entries cron
Nitrogento v1.2 provides a cron that clean every two hours old cache entries(this mechanism use the native magento cron feature so make sure that the cron.php is running on your system).`